# Change Text And Background Color Of Table Cell Based On Text Value

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a table with three columns as follows:

CATEGORY | ITEM | **STATUS**

The table is populated with data from a php script

I need to make sure that the cells under the header "STATUS" will change to be of red background and white text color if a value of "PRIORITY" is the result of the php data import.

Here is my js script

```
<script>
function c_color(){
if (document.getElementById('CellColor').value = 'PRIORITY') {
document.getElementById('CellColor').style.color = "white";
document.getElementById('CellColor').style.background="red";
}
}
c_color();
</script>
```

And this is the HTML/PHP that calls the function

```
<td id="CellColor" style="background-color: #92c38e; text-align: 
center;">
<span style="color: #ffffff; font-size: medium;">
<?php print strip_tags($category[0]['status']); ?></span></td>
```

As a result I get only the first cell with the red and white colors but this isn't even showing a value of "PRIORITY"

I have tried and re-tried but I can't get it right, any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What do you mean "the first cell", do you have more cells with the same ID ?

Comment: Is this table loading via an ajax call? what about just adding a 'priority' class to the cell?

Comment: @adeneo I meant that the first cell below the header "STATUS"

Comment: @vector the table cells values are populated by a PHP script that fetches the data via XML API call from a remote server

Comment: @Diego, is there a reason you don't add the appropriate classes at render time in php depending on what the value of status is? I'm assuming here the rows and cells get rendered in a loop of some sort, no?

Comment: @Vector Not sure how the right sintax is as I'm not normally dealing with PHP

Comment: @Diego, I put what I meant into an answer (better code formatting than in comments ;-) )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First let's fix the `function`:

```
function c_color(){
    if (document.getElementById('CellColor').value === 'PRIORITY') {
        document.getElementById('CellColor').style.color = "white";
        document.getElementById('CellColor').style.background="red";
    }
}
```

This modifies your assignment operator to comparison of `===`. Previously, you have given `'PRIORITY'` to the value and checked whether it is truey, which was always the case. However, I still do not like this `function`, let's refactor it a little bit:

```
function c_color(element){
    if (element.value === 'PRIORITY') {
        element.style.color = "white";
        element.style.background="red";
    }
}
```

and now it is much more understandable, and more importantly, reusable, since it does not assume that the `color` of a tag having a `CellColor` `id` should be changed if it has a priority value. Thirdly, it will have a better performance, since the function was searching for a tag three times in the DOM previously, while the approach I have given reuses the element. Now, to achieve the previous behavior, you will have to call the function like this:

```
c_color(document.getElementById('CellColor'))
```

Note that it has to be found once and then it is reused.

**The section below assumes that you have multiple instances of tags having the `id` of `CellColor`.**

Now, we still have a problem. You have a `CellColor` `id` which, if duplicate, then only the first corresponding item will be found using `document.getElementById` and your HTML is invalid, since `id` should be unique in the document. You can overcome your problem in hacky ways, but I do not recommend them. The hacky ways are to either use `document.querySelectorAll('#CellColor')`, which will return an array-like object to you with all the corresponding cells or to gather your `tr` items using `document.querySelectorAll` and while you iterate them, search for your item in their context using `getElementById`. However, as I said, I do not recommend them, since they overcomplicate your life and, more importantly, your HTML will still be invalid. Instead, the solution should be to modify `CellColor` to be a class instead of an `id`. Then, you could use `document.getElementsByClassName('CellColor')` or `document.querySelectorAll('.CellColor')`, or, if this is slow, search in the context of the ancestor `table` instead of `document`, like `document.getElementById("#yourtableid").getElementsByClassName('CellColor')`.

Comment: @ Lajos Arpad this worked fine and so we have another 10/10 Excellent job and many thanks for all your precious time and effort.

Answer (score 2):

Use `==` or `===` for **[comparison in JavaScript](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Equality_comparisons_and_sameness)**.

Your code:

```
if (document.getElementById('CellColor').value = 'PRIORITY')
```

assigns a value because it uses a single equal sign (which will always cause the `if` to enter the `true` branch).

Also, an HTML `td` element will not have a `value` property (only form elements do). Access the text contents of non-form elements with the **[`textContent`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/textContent)** property.

Additionally, make sure that your JavaScript code is either placed just before the closing of the `<body>` element or that you have it in a callback for the `window`'s `DOMContentLoaded` event to ensure that it doesn't run prior to the HTML elements it needs to use even being parsed.

---

Now, aside from those points, here's just a friendly "best-practice" suggestion. Try to get away from hard-coding or dynamically creating "inline styles" on HTML elements. That technique gets messy pretty quick and can create scalability issues because inline styles are very difficult to override when needed. Instead, write up CSS classes ahead of time and simply add or remove the classes as necessary.

Here's an example of that:

```js
// The following code won't run until all the HTML has been parsed into memory
window.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(){
  // Just scan the DOM for the element one time
  var theCell = document.getElementById('CellColor');
  
  // Here, we're just testing to see if the cell "contains" the text "PRIORITY",
  // not that it exactly equals it.
  if (theCell.textContent.indexOf('PRIORITY') > -1) {
    // Just add the pre-made class and you're done
    theCell.classList.add("special");
  }
});
```

```css
td {
  background-color: #92c38e;
  text-align: center;
}

.span {
  color: #ffffff; 
  font-size: medium;
}

.special {
  color:white;
  background-color:red;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td id="CellColor">PRIORITY
      <span class="span">span sample</span>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: I have tried this with both inline style and reference to external css but no result I am afraid. Right now I get no color at all. 
PS: When I run your code from the "run code snippet" funtion on this page it produces an error.

Comment: @Diego What browser are you using because I think you have a problem on your end? This is standard code and runs properly right here. You do have JavaScript enabled, right? The fact that you are getting an error and you can't get CSS to work points to a bigger issue.

Comment: Unfortunately also this edit did not produce the desired result. Perhaps if I show you the full script it would better? I am using Chrome and JavaScript is enabled

Comment: @Diego Again, the code here in this snippet is running as you asked for and as intended. If you can't get this code to run, you have a problem somewhere else.

Comment: correct, it is running now but got the error with your first edition. Anyway, unfortunately it doesn't run on my web page.

Comment: @Diego There must be other problems on your page.

Comment: it is Wordpress perhaps that is why.

Comment: @diego You should have mentioned that.  This would explain why you can't get CSS or this JavaScript to work. I'm not a word press guru, but I do know that there are special techniques that you must use to inject your own CSS and JavaScript.

Comment: posting on a different stack, many thanks for your patience, much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You can't use `getElementById` if you are going to have the same id for more than one element (as seen here https://jsfiddle.net/n7evzzer/). `getElementById` will only apply to the first result, as it only returns the first element that it finds in the DOM. This is also invalid syntax, and if you ran it through the HTML validator it would throw an error. A document should only have unique id's within it.

I would recommend that you use a class instead such as `priority`, and then color it based on the class.

Here you can do this 100% without JavaScript as seen here:

```css
td {
  text-align: center;
}

.priority {
  color: white;
  background: red;
}

td:not(.priority){
  color: white;
  background: #92c38e;
}
```

```html
<table>
    <tr>
      <td class="priority">
        <span>PRIORITY</span>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <span>NOT A PRIORITY</span>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="priority">
        <span>PRIORITY</span>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="priority">
        <span>PRIORITY</span>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <span>NOT A PRIORITY</span>
      </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion, however in my case that would not work as the text inside the cells is populated dynamically by a PHP code so I have no control where the cell with text of value "PRIORITY" will end up to. By using the class the way you display you must know in advance where the "PRIORITY" data will be.

Answer (score 0):

... what about something like this. Add a class attribute and then add some css to color it:

```
.priority{
color:#fff;
background-color:red;
}

<td><span 
style="color: #ffffff; font-size: medium;" 
class="<?=strtolower($category[0]['status'])?>">

<?php print strip_tags($category[0]['status']); ?></span></td>
```